# How to create update button without page refresh

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have my items:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>
            id
        </th>
        <th>
            name
        </th>
        <th>
            update
        </th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <?php echo $id; ?>
        </td>
        <td>
            <?php echo $name; ?>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="button" name="id" id="update" value="update" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Now I want when I click on update button to load `update.php?id=$id` result under the button
How can I make this in JavaScript?
Please help me.

Comment: No, no.. please understand that Java is NOT the same as JavaScript!

Comment: Use JavaScript not Java and read about AJAX

Comment: @TraianTatic I wish I could upvote your comment multiple times...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a basic example of content load via JavaScript, using the JQuery library:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>
            id
        </th>
        <th>
            name
        </th>
        <th>
            update
        </th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <?php echo $id; ?>
        </td>
        <td>
            <?php echo $name; ?>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input class="toLoad" link="update.php?id=<?php echo $id; ?>" type="button" name="id" id="update" value="update" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td id="results"></td>
    </tr>
</table>


<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(".toLoad").click( function(event)
{
        event.preventDefault();
        $("#results").load($(this).attr("link"));
});
</script>
```

Not tested, should work. In case it's not working, please reply with the error you are getting.

Comment: thank you very very very much. it has work successful

Comment: @user3932710 Happy to hear that. The logic behind it is not that complex so you should be able to modify it in the future to fit other requirements.

Answer (score 0):

First give an id to the  where your button is in.

```
<td id="main">
    <input type="button" name="id" id="update" value="update" />
</td>
```

Then include the JQuery library to your `<head></head>` section

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js" ></script>
```

Add an ajax call when you push the button

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('input[name="id"].click(function(){
        $.ajax({
          url : 'update.php',
          type : "POST",
          data : {
                id  : '<?php echo($id); ?>'
          },
          success : function(data) {
            $('#main').append(data);
          }
      });
    });
}
```

When you click the button an ajax call is made to the php page where you must `echo` the result,
this will be displayed after the button.